# Basic Expressjs query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The question might sound confusing and stupid. I've just started with nodejs.

Anyways, I've a form and when a user submits it I want to display an html element with a response. So, I used the body parser and displayed it with the jade view engine.

**The problem** - To display the result with bodyParser, I've to create an html element with the variable beforehand `p #{url}` (It sits empty until the response)and I also need the response to fadein but I can't do that with the view engine. Is there a way to share the server side variable to another javascript file, so that I can use jquery? What's the best practice to  do it?

**What I've tried so far** - I read a bunch of question saying to do it with ajax but I wasn't able to figure how to get the response from the server to the file with ajax. `res.send` `res.json` and some other stuff that didn't work.

index.jade

```
extends ../public/layouts/default

block content
    #onlydiv
        #onlydiv-inside
            p Paste your URL below to shorten it
            form#urlform(action='/add', method='post')
                input#area(type='text' name='url', placeholder = 'www.facebook.com', autocomplete = 'off' required)
                input#button(type='submit')
            p #{url}
```

Route

```
var express = require('express');
var url = require('.././models/first.js');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index');
    res.end();
})

router.post('/add',function(req,res) {
    var patt = /(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
    var url = req.body.url;
    if(patt.test(url) === false) {
        res.render('index', {
            url : 'Invalid Url'
        })
    } else {
        res.render('index', {
            url : 'Invalid Url'
        })
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: To clarify, your issue is fading in the element? If this is the case move the code from your `post` route to your jquery file first. Then on form submit run your jquery url validation. If it doesnt pass stop the form submit and show the error. You should always validate on ther server side too regardless of client side validation

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, your issue is fading in the element? If this is the case move the code from your `post` route to your jquery file first.

Then do something like:

```
$('#urlform').on('submit', function(){
    var patt = /(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
    var url = $("input[name=url]").val();
    if(patt.test(url) === false) {
        $("#urlerr").html("Invalid URL").fadeIn("slow");
        return false;
    }
});

<div id="onlydiv">
  <div id="onlydiv-inside">
    <p>Paste your URL below to shorten it</p>
    <form id="urlform" action="" method="">
      <input id="area" type="text" name="url" placeholder="www.facebook.com" autocomplete="off" required="required"/>
      <input id="button" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <p id="urlerr" style="display: none;"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrmp7c6n/11/#&togetherjs=I8p5Unmi3G)